# C/C++ how to decrease float's number of significant decimals of a variable

Tags: c++, c, floating-point

Generating a random number between [0, 1.0]

```
i = (float) rand() / RAND_MAX / 1;
```

I don't just want to print one decimal point, i want the variable to have one decimal point
How do we do that?

(i.e.  0.1 ;  not 0.1224828)

Comment: Try as hard as you want. The variable is always going to have more than one.

Comment: Multiply by ten, floor, divide by ten?

Comment: @chris boy were you wrong

Comment: @echadromani, I didn't know you meant rounding it to one decimal place. Even if you do, it can still be 0.600000001. You're not ever going to make a float simply 0.6 or 0.8 or whatever you will unless it's a value that's able to be represented exactly.

Comment: @chris checkout david or alex's answer

Comment: @echadromani What chris means is what I state in the final paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @chris I see what you meant. It's not for printing though, so i don't think it'll make much of a difference in this context

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you actually describe is a random integer with possible values in the range 0 to 10. So you would write:

```
int i = rand() / (RAND_MAX / 11 + 1);
```

or indeed some other way to generate an integer `i` such that 0 <= i <= 10.

Now, `i` is your value scaled by 10.

If you then want to divide by 10, do just that:

```
float f = i / 10.0;
```

Do be aware that a binary floating point variable cannot exactly represent 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8 and 0.9. The only values in your list that can be exactly expressed are 0.0, 0.5 and 1.0. This is why it is better to store the information in an integer variable.

*Note*: As has been pointed by others (thank you), the obvious `rand() % 11` has poor randomness properties. I updated the answer to avoid using that.

Comment: You might find [this page](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/random.html) to be an interesting read.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue, Too bad there's no mention of `<random>` (yes, I know it's older than C++11).

Answer (score 3):

When you store a value 'R' in a floating-point variable, you don't often get to store 'R'. Instead, you have to store the legitimate floating-point value that's *closest* to 'R'. [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/fp/printfprec.html)

Even if you're not trying to produce random integers within a range, you should read [How can I get random integers in a certain range?](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html)  This expression

```
(int)((double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1) * N)
```

is better than the obvious `rand() % N`; Also, its lessons apply in other contexts.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: If you have to write a lot of code in C, read that FAQ from front to back once a month.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
i = ((float)( rand()%11) ) /10;
```

Comment: This does not compile, because `%` does not accept `float` operands. Also, `%` is a poor way to distribute values from `rand` because it clusters the extra values (due to RAND_MAX+1 not being a multiple of the modulus) at the low end of the interval.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Fixed brackets, but what is a better way to get the distribution in a fixed range?

Comment: If your application is okay with a slightly non-uniform distribution, then you can use code such as that in [another answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15684059/298225), which spreads the excess values throughout the interval, although in certain circumstances floating-point rounding can be an issue. If your application needs a completely uniform distribution, then the excess values must be rejected and a new random value selected (hence a loop that runs until a satisfactory result is obtained).